# How to pass window handle to wndproc?

Tags: winapi

I have written this code in c# application for tracking messages ...

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
{
    // Listen for operating system messages.
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
         case WM_CHAR:
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("d:/Type.txt",FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write);
                //set up a streamwriter for adding text
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);                      
                sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);                       
                int no=(int)m.WParam;   
                sw.Write(Convert.ToChar(no));                        
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();

                break;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

I want to track messages for different window so how can I pass different window handle to wndproc ? please help me...

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to register global keyboard hook instead of passing different handle. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) article shows how to do that. Basic idea behind that is that you register your function for polling all keyboard-related system events (for every message) and filter out only those you need.

The functionality is achieved with [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) winapi function.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter all the messages in the application by calling `Application.AddMessageFilter(IMessageFilter filter)` at the beginning of your program.

The `IMessageFilter` interface has just one method:

```
bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m);
```

That is called for every message handled by the application. There you can use `m.HWnd` to identify the different windows of your program.

Comment: Actually I want to track messages from any active window. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Windows that belong to other applications? Then you need a global hook, as Dmitriy Reznik told in his answer.

Comment: is there any alternative or how to use it ?

Comment: Alternative? That's how it is done, and Dmitriy already linked the official docs. You could also write a layered keyboard driver, of course, but that would be too much work for no gain.